# Creating the Yin Yang symbol with minimal code

Tags: graphics, programming, geometry, code-golf

The following code creates the Yin Yang symbol

```
Graphics[{Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], White, 
   DiskSegment[{0, 0}, 1, {1/2 \[Pi], 3/2 \[Pi]}],
   Black, DiskSegment[{0, 0}, 1, {3/2 \[Pi], 5/2 \[Pi]}], White, 
   Disk[{0, 0.5}, 0.5],
   Black, Disk[{0, -0.5}, 0.5], Black, Disk[{0, 0.5}, 0.125],
   White, Disk[{0, -0.5}, 0.125]
   }] // Show
```

Knowing that 'there is always someone who can do things with less code', I wondered what the optimal way is, in Mathematica, to create the Yin Yang symbol.

Not really an urgent question to a real problem, but a challenge, a puzzle, if you like. I hope these kind of questions can still be asked here.

Comment: Teeny reduction in code:  Replace `Black,Circle[{0,0},1]` with `Circle[]`, and eliminate `// Show`.

Comment: There are some great animations online; see for instance https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/YinYangAndMore/ https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ANewKindOfYinYangRotation/  https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/YinYang/

Certainly not minimal code, but maybe noteworthy

Comment: Nice, thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
d = {#, 0} ~ Disk ~ ##2 &; 

Graphics@{d[4, 8, {0, π}], 8~d~4, {White, 0~d~4, d@8}, d@0, Circle @@ 4~d~8}
```

[image]

```
StringLength @ "d={#,0}~Disk~##2&
Graphics@{d[4,8,{0,π}],8~d~4,White,0~d~4,d@8},d@0,Circle@@4~d~8}"
```

> ```
> 83
> ```

We can get the rotated version at a cost of three additional characters: Replace  `{#, 0}` with `{0,#}` and `{0, π}` with `{3, 5} π/2` to get

[image]

Comment: I think this was the kind of answer I hoped for. A 'functional programming' solution.

Comment: By moving the outer circle to the end, the outer edge looks cleaner (no more line-thinning at 9 o'clock): `d[y_,a___]:={4y,0}~Disk~a;Graphics@{d[0,8,{0,π}],1~d~4,White,d[-1,4],d@1,Black,d@-1,{0,0}~Circle~8}`

Comment: Thank you @Roman. Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: I see that your answer evolved...!  Even for you the statement: 'there is always someone who can do things with less code' was true. ;-)

Comment: just asked in Code Golf SE: [Diagram of the Utmost Extremes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/240166/85527)

Answer (score 33):

[Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/262F/):

```
\:262F
(*    ☯    *)
```

For post-processing at higher resolution, we can [rasterize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) this character to arbitrary pixel counts:

```
Rasterize[\:262F, RasterSize -> 1000] // ImageCrop
```

[image]

Comment: Or... `Show[Graphics[Text[Style["☯", 84]]],
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True},
 ImageSize -> 80]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - `Graphics` doesn't need `Show`, e.g., `Graphics[Text[Style["☯", 288]], Method -> "ShrinkWrap" -> True]`

Comment: DavidG.Stork Nice, but I get a rather thick frame around it.

Comment: `Style["\:262F", 288]` is enough, no need for wrappers like `Text`, `Graphics`, `Show`, `ShrinkWrap`, ...

Comment: @Roman - You definitely delivered what was asked: minimal code. But sadly, the Graphics Editor does not work on the output, and it can't be processed further with MMa code.

Comment: What about `Rasterize[\:262F, ImageResolution -> 10000] // ImageCrop`? It generates an [`Image`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html) of size $1063\times1062$ for further use.

Comment: You could also mesh it:
`Graphics[{Purple,ImageMesh@ColorNegate@ImageCrop@DeleteBorderComponents@Rasterize@Style["☯", FontSize -> 4^5]}]`

Comment: +1 for the win IMO...

Answer (score 20):

I think the code in the OP is nice and concise, and generates a good graphic.  But if brevity is the goal, you can turn to the Knowledgebase via

```
Graphics[Interpreter["Character"]["yin yang symbol"]["Glyph"]]
```

[image]

Longer code, but gives a nice football shape:

```
Plot[{Sin @ x, Sin[2 * x] / 2, -Sin[x]},
    {x, 0, Pi},
    Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Black}, 3 -> {2, White}},
    Axes -> False,
    PlotStyle -> {None, Black, Black},
    Epilog -> {{White,Disk[{(2 \[Pi])/3.,1/3},0.1]},{Black,Disk[{\[Pi]/3.,-(1/3)},0.1]}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Very original indeed, the concept can be applied to various base-forms. - Imagine code to 'Yin Yang - inize' any base form, 2D or 3D. Just thinking out aloud.

Answer (score 16):

Not shorter, just different

```
RegionPlot[{
  x^2 + y^2 < 7, 
  x > Sin[y] && x^2 + y^2 < 7, 
  (x - .2)^2 + (y + 1.5)^2 < .2, 
  (x + .2)^2 + (y - 1.5)^2 < .2},
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotStyle -> {White, Black, White, Black}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Black, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely clearer than my code.

Comment: But the true ying-yang uses *circles*... not a sine wave.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - Yes, let's call it "yin-yang-inspired"...

Comment: sin-yang (interpretation of `sin` deliberately left ambiguous)

Answer (score 12):

As a plot with `Filling`:

```
Plot[{-Sqrt[1 - (x - Sign@x)^2] Sign@x, Sqrt[4 - x^2], -Sqrt[4 - x^2]}
 , {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {3}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, FillingStyle -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> Black, Axes -> False, Exclusions -> None, 
 Epilog -> {Disk[{1, 0}, .3], White, Disk[{-1, 0}, .3]}]
```

[image: yin yang as a Plot]

With region operations, and golfed:

```
d = Disk; c = {1, 0}; Graphics@{Circle[0 c, 2], 
 DiscretizeRegion@RegionDifference[RegionUnion[d[0 c, 2, {0, π}], d[c, 1]], 
    d[-c, 1]], d[-c, .2], White, d[c, .2]}
```

[image: yin yang]

Comment: With all the air squeezed out it will just about fit into 138 characters.

Answer (score 9):

```
l = Line /@ Transpose @ Map[{#, ({0, 1} + #)/2, ({0, -1} + {-1, 1} #)/2} &] @
     CirclePoints[{1, -π/2}, 50][[;; 26]];

Graphics@{Circle[], FilledCurve @ l, Disk[{0, 1/2}, 1/8], White, Disk[{0, -1/2}, 1/8]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://tieba.baidu.com/p/2578898520) in Chinese community:

```
With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], θ = ArcTan[x, y]}, 
 RegionPlot[(Cos[θ - r] - Sin[θ]) 
            (r^4 - 2 r^2 Cos[2 θ + 24/10] + 9/10) + (62/100 r)^1000 < 0, 
        {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 67]]
```

[image]